# How to download a ZIP file on all browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

This is what I currently have:

**express.js**

```
app.get('/downloadZip', function(req, res) {
  var file = req.query.downloadURL;
  var filename = path.basename(file);
  var mimetype = 'application/zip';

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment');
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

  var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  filestream.pipe(res);
});
```

**my controller**

```
$http({
  method: "GET",
  url: '/downloadZip',
  params: {
    downloadURL: 'myZip.zip'
  },
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).then(
  function success(data, status, headers, config) {
    $log.debug('downloadZip success: ', data);

    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
    // using FileSaver.js
    saveAs(blob, 'newZipName.zip');
  },
  function error(error) {
    $log.debug('downloadZip error: ', error);
  });
```

With this approach, it seems to find the file ok - the `$log.debug` output shows an ArrayBuffer of 5Mb for `data`, which is the correct file size. BUT, the file is always downloaded as 1Kb, and obviously won't open.

I'm trying FileSaver.js in the example above, but I also tried using `angular.element('<a/>')`, etc - and it always results in 1Kb downloads.

*Is there anything I can do to download the full ZIP correctly?*

**Edit:**

I figured it out - see answer below. One of those stupid mistakes. But at least there's some nice free code above for anyone who wants to download ZIPs ;)

Comment: If you would tell me what your website is then i could probably break it. `/downloadZip?downloadURL=package.json`

Comment: @Endless Interesting. Would you be able to suggest a safer approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed was `data.data`.

Because this was the contents of the received `data` object:

```
Object {data: ArrayBuffer, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

So I had to specify the child `data` that contained the ArrayBuffer...

```
var blob = new Blob([data.data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
```